# Efficiency of computer Network

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question that was an extra question in one of my math books.

I have $n$ computers.

Each computer owns a file, named like the computer. For example, computer 1 (C1) owns file 1 (F1). To make sure the file isn't lost when the computer breaks, it is backed up on 3 other computers of the network. So every computer has its own file and 3 backup files of other computers, for example:

```
C1: F1; F3, F4, F7
```

Every file is saved 4 times. Once on its owner and 3 times as a backup.

When there are 10 or more computers, it is possible to make sure that you will never have more than 2 identical files on 2 random computers. This shall always be the case.

My question is how to calculate the probability of some events:

```
Event A:  n=10, four machines break down: P(1 file lost)
Event B:  n=10, four machines break down: P(0 file lost)
Event C:  n=10, five machines break down: P(1 file lost)
Event D:  n=10, k machines break down: P(x files lost); k<=10, x<=k
Event E:  n, k machines break down: P(x files lost); n element of N>=10, k<=n, x<=k
```

I am really struggling to calculate these probabilities. It seems to me that "E" will need the most explaination and explains the solution of the 
other events as well. You can only provide a solution for E, if you like, but all other help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you might wanna check your post again for typos and other errors.

Comment: Same to you for Typos, colloquial language, etc.